# Zabbix server doesn't start

Tags: devops, zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I'm getting the following error when I run the **sudo systemctl restart zabbix-server.service** How can I solve this? I have already installed apache,Zabbix. I have check the log from **sudo systemctl status zabbix-server.service** and check the error log from ***journalctl -xe***

```
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- enter code here
-- The unit zabbix-server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
Oct 07 10:24:57 ts systemd[1]: Failed to start Zabbix Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit zabbix-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit zabbix-server.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 97394 and the job result is failed.
Oct 07 10:25:01 ts CRON[50919]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 07 10:25:01 ts CRON[50920]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 07 10:25:01 ts CRON[50919]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 07 10:25:07 ts systemd[1]: zabbix-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 12.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit zabbix-server.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Oct 07 10:25:07 ts systemd[1]: Stopped Zabbix Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit zabbix-server.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit zabbix-server.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 97466 and the job result is done.
Oct 07 10:25:07 ts systemd[1]: Starting Zabbix Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit zabbix-server.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit zabbix-server.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 97466.
Oct 07 10:25:09 ts systemd[1]: zabbix-server.service: Can't open PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_server.p>
Oct 07 10:25:09 ts systemd[1]: zabbix-server.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit zabbix-server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
Oct 07 10:25:09 ts systemd[1]: Failed to start Zabbix Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit zabbix-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit zabbix-server.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 97466 and the job result is failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Can't open PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_server.p` Create /run/zabbix directory with proper permissions.

Comment: I had the /run/zabbix directory (644,zabbix:zabbix). I also had tu create the zabbix_server.pid (755,zabbix:zabbix) in order to start the service
(after upgdate von ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 and zabbix 5.5 to 6)